# Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS) get all lists in Address book

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm developing web application (ASP.NET) with VB.

I will like to get all Address Lists from Address Book and also all Groups and Email Contacts for each list in Address book.

How can I do that? Any suggestion?

I'm using Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS). Is this the right way?

Thanks for answer and best regards,

Filip

Comment: You haven't really given enough information, What is your application going to do ? where is it going to be run (eg is it an Outlook Plugin etc). EWS doesn't have the ability to do what your trying to do so you will need probably to use LDAP to get the Global Address List side of it and then maybe EWS to get the local contacts if needed but you haven't really given enough information in your question.

Comment: I will like to show user all available email addresses so that he can pick one I at the end send the email. Important is that user can see all groups and also all user inside each group. All this information will be on simple asp.net page.

Answer (score 2):

EWS is limited in what it can do with Accessing to the Directory there are 2 EWS operations ResolveName https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645423%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx and ExpandGroup https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629392(v=exchg.150).aspx that give limited address book function. On 2013 there is FindPeople https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx which can do a lot more. I would suggest you start with these write some code yourself to see how they work.

All the directory information that Exchange accesses in the Global Address list is in Active Directory so I  you will most probably need to use LDAP directory to Access Active Directory if you application needs more complex directory access.

Cheers
Glen